# OpenShift - The requested URL /app was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, apache, dns, openshift

I am using OpenShift server and I am trying to set up my recently purchased custom domain. It is pointing to OpenShift's CNAME, but when I try to access my site (WordPress) I am getting the following error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /app was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at www.outdooradventureclubgc.com Port
>   443

Answer (score 1):

You only have the alias outdooradventureclubgc.com set on your application, you also need to add the alias www.outdooradventureclubgc.com since that is what you are pointing to your application.  The www.outdooradventureclubgc.com does not get added automatically when you setup the naked domain alias.

Comment: By adding www alias I got "too many loops" from Chrome, plus the "Not found" page is still there.